# Не устанавливается Grub загрузчик

Tags: linux, grub

Всех приветствую!
Недавно я переустановил Windows, после чего я решил поставить 2й системой Linux, на отдельный диск (раздел). Все установилось нормально, за исключением Grub загрузчика, после включения ноутбука у меня сразу же загружается Windows.
Далее, с LiveCD я попытался установить загрузчик вручную.
В первый раз я решил установить Grub на системный загрузчик Windows

```
sudo su
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda1
```

Во второй раз попытался поставить на сам раздел с линуксом:

```
sudo su
mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda4
```

Так же я пробовал прописать такие же команды установки Grub, но из последнего значения я убирал цифру раздела (получалось: `grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda`)
Но в каждом из этих случаях вылезали ошибки:

```
WARNING: tempfile is deprecated; consider using mktemp instead. 
WARNING: tempfile is deprecated; consider using mktemp instead. 
The file /mnt/boot/grub/stage1 not read correctly.
```

Хотя, когда я монтирую диск с линуксом, в дирректории /mnt/boot/grub файл stage1 присутствует!

Можете помочь пожалуйста установить этот Grub загрузчик?

**UPD:** При установке, Linux не видит 2ю систему Windows.

Comment: Охох, а что за дистрибутив?

Comment: Kali Linux. LiveCD тоже на нем.

Comment: залезь в биос и проверь, какой загрузчик в приоритете. Вполне может быть, что приоритетным стоит windows boot manager и поэтому сразу грузится винда

Comment: Нашел только 2 настройки: Windows boot manager (P4 HGST HTS.........) - загрузчик винды и P2: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GT90N - это дисковод. Больше там ничего нет.

Answer (score 1):

GRUB не видит загрузчик Windows из-за отключенного os-prober. Отредактируйте /etc/default/grub, там должна быть строчка `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false`. Раскомментируйте её (она обычно закомментирована) и укажите false явно. И сделайте:

```
# Подразумевается, что вы загрузили установленный
# дистрибутив или зашли в него через chroot
 ~ $ sudo apt install os-prober
# и уже затем
 ~ $ sudo update-grub
```

И все. Сам так делал, когда пытался поставить Kali рядом с UEFI-шной Windows. И да, если у вас потом все равно будет грузиться Windows, поменяйте в BIOS приоритет загрузки на диск с Linux. Если же у вас UEFI - то же самое, но если у вас появился пункт linux, kali, grub или что-то такое, то ставьте его дефолтным.

Comment: Не сработало. Я решил посмотреть системы на диске: Если я прописываю команду os-prober с флешки, то выводится только система Kali Linux, если пишу через chroot, то не выводится вообще ничего.

Comment: как у вас разбиты диски?

Comment: Слишком много букв, вставил на Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/sK4rALzZ

Answer (score 1):

[Попробуйте этот сайт](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_grub)

А если быть конкретней то раздел "Восстановление используя chroot", мне в одно время помогло.
Если кратко, то вот что помогло мне:

`sudo fdisk -l` - просмотреть разделы на диске, линуксовый нужно монтировать с ещё несколькими директориями
`sudo mount /dev/лр /mnt` - лр: линуксовый раздел

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys
```

Потом переходите в chroot

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

И устанавливайте grub

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

В случае ошибок:

```
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck --no-floppy /dev/sda
```

После прописывайте `exit` чтобы выйти с чрут и отмонтируете разделы

```
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt
```

И перезагружаетесь, можете также проверить сайт выше, там подробней и другие способы, я расписал который подошёл мне

А по поводу ошибки `The file /mnt/boot/grub/stage1 not read correctly.`
То попробуйте `grub-install --recheck /dev/sda`,
или перейдите на [сайт](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Talk:GRUB_Legacy#:%7E:text=If%20you%20get%20an%20error,grub%20shell%20or%20grub%2Dinstall.), там есть ещё некоторые варианты которые могут служить появлению проблемы

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin прошу прощения, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Увы, не помогло.